# C++ how to clear vector but not free memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a class `Test` which contains one member variable `vector<MyCls> m_vObj` and two member functions `clear_vec` and `func`. Please see the following code.

The `func` has a `for` loop, and each time it will `push_back` some instances into `m_vObj`, do some computation, and output the computation results. After that, I call `clear_vec` to clear the `m_vObj` vector, and prepare for the next loop.

Currently, I `swap` the `m_vObj` with an empty vector according to [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10465032/2468587). But I find the member function `clear_vec` is time-consuming especially for the `swap`(line 1).

As far as I understand, I just need to clear all elements in `m_vObj` and I do not need to free the memory. However, `clear_vec` in the `for` loop will frequently allocate memory and free memory. If I comment line 1 and just keep line 2, I can clear the vector but do not re-allocate memory frequently. Is it safe and will it be more efficient?

```
class Test {
private:
    vector<MyCls> m_vObj;

public:
    void clear_vec() {
        vector<MyCls>().swap(m_vObj); // line 1
        m_vObj.clear(); // line 2
    }

    void func() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {

            // push_back some instances into m_vObj
            // do some computations with m_vObj
            // output computation results

            clear_vec();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `line 2` is redundant with `line 1`. `m_vObj` is already empty because you swapped it with a default constructed (empty) vector.

Comment: `clear()` leaves the capacity (i.e. the allocated memory) unchanged.

Comment: I believe the dupe should answer your question. If not, please clarify why `clear()` does not fulfill your goal and ping me so I can reopen.

Comment: The swap trick is to free-up the memory. You dont need to do that so it's not the trick for you. Clear will empty the vector so it does what you need and is "safe". It doesnt free the memory so it should be faster than a version that does have to allocate memory each time round the loop - (especially if it has to allocate more than once due to the vector out-growing its exsiting capacity).

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thank you. I read many related questions including the one you mentioned, but all of them are talking about how to completely free the memory of vector. That's not what I want. I want to clear the elements in vector and in the same time not to free the memory, as I need to reuse the memory for the next loop. So, I want to ask is it safe and enough to only use `clear` and no need to use the `swap`.

Comment: @ROX Thank you. Your answer reassures me. I also think I do not need the `swap` trick, as I do not want to free and re-allocate the memory.