# C++: Freeing the memory from vector of objects

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have this situation where my program starts to slow down and eventually halts. I am guessing it is due to not claiming memory in a right way. Can anyone please help me what is the correct way to free memory in this case?

simplified definitions:

```
typedef struct {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<metric_t> metrics;
} region_t;


typedef struct {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<region_t> regions;
} data_t;


typedef struct {
    std::string name;
    std::vector<double> means;
} metric_t;
```

Main loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    data_t data;
    prepare_data(&data);

    /* Usage of data here */
}
```

prepare data function:

```
void prepare_data(data_t * data)
{
    region_t new_region;

    data->regions.push_back(new_region);

    for(int j=0; j< 100000; j++)
    {
        metric_t new_metric;
        /* put some data in new_metric */
        data->regions.back().metrics.push_back(new_metric);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to do anything special to free memory for these vectors.

Comment: Unrelated note: that `typedef` is pointless. In C++ you write `struct data_t { ... }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Right" way to deallocate an std::vector object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054567/right-way-to-deallocate-an-stdvector-object)

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Maybe you need to increase the heap size or something like that.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. If the first few iterations of main loop run okay, doesn't that mean that stack is enough for the `data` structure?

Comment: No, actually the vector gets bigger and bigger as the loop progresses. What IDE are you using to run the code?

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar I am using Eclipse Kepler. Isn't `data` destroyed at the end of each iteration of "main loop" as it is defined inside? So if initial few iteration works okay, doesn't that mean that there is enough room for 100000 elements?

Comment: Please also post the definition of `metric_t`.

Comment: Did the `reserve` suggestion given by **Humam** help?

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar: *"No, actually the vector gets bigger"* - Cashif asked if he could conclude that the stack was enough for the `data` structure, and the correct answer to that is "yes": the stack usage doesn't grow from one loop iteration to the next.  When the `vector` gets bigger it increases its dynamic memory (heap) usage.

Comment: @TonyD Yes that is right.

Comment: @CashifIlyas Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar No. But I guess I didn't explain the problem correctly here.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple: any `new` must be balanced with a `delete`, and any `new[]` balanced with a `delete[]`.

The standard C++ library container classes obey these rules so unless you've written `new` or `new[]` yourself (which you haven't), all the memory cleanup will be done for you.

The cause of any performance problem lies elsewhere: I think it's due to **your pushing elements to a vector one-by-one a large number of times** (which will cause multiple reallocations of memory). Perhaps use a `std::list` rather than a `std::vector`?

Don't worry about the fact that `data` is an *automatic* variable: `sizeof(data)` is small.

Also, avoid `_t` suffixes if you can: POSIX disallows that (although many folk give no quarter since the C++ standard *does* allow you to do this). Plus there's no need for the `typedef` around your `struct` definitions in C++.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You suggested that allocating memory one by one might be slowing it down. I am not concerned about the speed but the problem is, it works okay for `i` less than about 30 or so and then it starts to halt.

Comment: I am indeed suggesting that. Try using std::list.

Comment: Or use .reserve(100000) to allocate enough memory for all of your data, it will remove overhead with memory reallocations, and you won't have to change your application.

Comment: `std::list` requires a lot more distinct dynamic allocations, with associated overheads - it will use considerably more memory and time than a pre-reserved `vector`, though it's less susceptible to fragmentation-related failures.

Comment: The acid test, of course, is to try it and profile it. The *current* approach is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have any dynamic memory management (i.e. calls to `new` or `new[]`) so there is nothing you need to do. Everything will automatically be freed when the declaration scope ends.

Maybe you have a different problem? You may want to use a profiler and get some data.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any memory mangment problem. `std::vector` is doing everything for you. However, This should give you a better performance:

```
void prepare_data(data_t * data){
    region_t new_region;
    data->regions.push_back(new_region);
    data->regions.back().metrics.reserve(100000);
    for(int j=0; j< 100000; j++){
        metric_t new_metric;
        /* put some data in new_metric */
        data->regions.back().metrics.push_back(new_metric);
        //data->regions.back().metrics.emplace_back(a1,a2,...); if you can construct metric_t directly here it would be better
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To know if you are leaking memory either use some tool for monitoring process resource usage your operating system has (e. g. `htop` on `linux`) or code analyzer (e. g. `valgrind` on `linux`).

There might be other issues than pushing back to `std::vector` without calling `reserve()`. Default memory buffer growth strategy is exponential.

Comment: "is exponential" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Bathsheba Every time `std::vector` has not enough memory for element to be inserted size of it's buffer is doubled (other factors like 1.5 could be used). It means that buffer is growing exponentially.

Comment: Interesting. Does the C++ standard *mandate* that? I *thought* it was smarter than that.

Comment: @Bathsheba I find it actually pretty smart default strategy. It is not mandated by standard. See e. g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232198/about-vectors-growth